# String, Int Differentiation and Looping in Python

Tags: python

How to complete my program which repeatedly reads numbers until the user enters
“done”. Once “done” is entered, print out the total, count, and average of
the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a number, detect their mistake
using try and except and print an error message and skip to the next number.

```
count = 0
total = 0

while True:
  x = raw_input('Enter number')
  x=int(x)
  total = total + x
  count = count + 1
  average = total / count
  print total, count, average
```

Comment: Did you even try using an exception to catch the integer conversion error? As I see it all you really need to do is unindent the last line, add the check for `done` and the exception.

Comment: Try again and show us more effort

Comment: Start by googling for 'python' and 'exception'

Comment: A `while True:` loop without a `break` in it somewhere could run for a _very_ long time.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should be what you want.

```
count = 0
total = 0

while True:
    x = raw_input('Enter number: ')
    if(x.lower() == "done"):
        break
    else:
        try:
            x=int(x)
            total = total + x
            count = count + 1
            average = total / count
        except:
            print("That is not an integer. Please try again.")

print total, count, average
```

or in Python 3

```
count = 0
total = 0

while True:
    x = input('Enter number: ')
    if(x.lower() == "done"):
        break
    else:
        try:
            x=int(x)
            total = total + x
            count = count + 1
            average = total / count
        except:
            print("That is not an integer. Please try again.")

print(total, count, average)
```